# What Permission level is required to trigger a workflow that creates a list item?

Tags: workflow

I have a user that can create a list item with Contribute access. When he manually triggers a workflow it tells him he doesn't have access.

The workflow simply creates a new item with the same data from the list item it's run on.

When he requests access, I get a pending request for access for the sites PARENT site.

Help?

Comment: Does your workflow involve multiple lists, ie, create item in a list based on an item in a different list?

Comment: Luckily no - I'd thought of that :/

Comment: Does your workflow create item in the same list or in a different list?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

your user need "Design" as minimum permission

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working because they have Design. That's what has been tripping me up..

Comment: witch type of workflow you create ex. "List, Reusable or site" workflow?